# Using Locale from Resource Bundle in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, locale

I'm learning to use resouce bundle for printing locale-dependent messages in my project.

application.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="ru.bpc.svat.svnr.integration.banking.messages" />
</bean>
<bean class="ru.bpc.svat.svnr.integration.banking.application.SpringContextMessageFactory"  />
```

Directory src\main\resources\ru\bpc\svat\svnr\integration\banking contains files:

```
messages.properties
messages_ru.properties
messages_ru_RU.properties
```

each having line:

```
test = testmessage
```

In my test class I get an instance of message factory and try to get a message:

```
@Autowired private MessageFactory messageFactory;
...
messageFactory.getMessage("test", new Object[]{}, Locale.getDefault());
```

And then I get an exception:

```
No message found under code 'test' for locale 'ru_RU'.
```

What's wrong with it? This might be a foolish question, but it's my first experience. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: The solution is below: add id="messageSource" to bean definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>locale\customer\messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

finally use SpringContext context.getMessage() method read your value.

**Note:** Assume your properties  files are located at “resources\locale\customer\” folder.as mentioned in value tag above.
Basically those files needs to be in class-path of your project.

Let me know if it solves your problem, then accept my answer!

Comment: The problem was I thought bean id does not matter. That's wrong, it has to be specified this way: id="messageSource"

Answer (score 0):

what if you place you files directly into src/main/resources (& not in subdirectory of src/main/resources?  Just a thought.Normally, it should be able to find the file if it is there on classpath.

Comment: It did not help (Idea automatically changed path to resources)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="ru.bpc.svat.svnr.integration.banking.messages" />
</bean>
```

on

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="ru\bpc\svat\svnr\integration\banking\messages" />
</bean>
```

make sure that the path relative from your class. In other case put resource in src/main/resources and use classpath:\ suffix